# Get a selector property value defined through a mixin with SASS

Tags: sass

Is it possible to get the value of a property defined through a mixin for a selector within another selector. For example:

```
@mixin mymixin($mywidth) {
  width: $mywidth;
}

div {
  @include mymixin(90%);
}

p {
  width: (20 / (([GET_SOMEWAY_DIV_WIDTH] * 960) / 100)) * 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable:

```
$mywidth: 90%;

div {
    width: $mywidth;
}

p {
    width: (20 / (($mywidth * 960) / 100)) * 100;
}
```

---

***Edit*** re: OP edit. AFAICS, when using mixin arguments, those values are only accessible within the scope of the mixin, when the mixin is included. Refactor so that you pass a variable to the included mixin:

```
$mywidth: 90%;

@mixin mymixin($mywidth) {
  width: $mywidth;
}

div {
  @include mymixin($mywidth);
}

p {
  width: (20 / (($mywidth * 960) / 100)) * 100;
}
```

Comment: Ok, sorry, I forgot something important in my question. The property is defined through a mixin. I updated the question. Thank you.